# Where is the documentation on boto's filters?

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto

Throughout the [boto ec2 documentation](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html), anything that accepts a filter advises you to "Check the EC2 API guide for details."  Googling around I see a few supported filters, but I can't find an exhaustive list.  Help!

Answer (score 2):

Oh I get it now.  When I read "EC2 API guide" I was expecting boto documentation.  But they mean AWS documentation:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/query-apis.html